# External NVMe slow once?

Tags: linux, kubuntu, nvme

I’ve bought an external NVMe and the first time I’ve tried to copy a (large) folder it was super slow.

I’ve immediately thought of some defects but smartctl doesn’t report anything wrong, then I’ve tried again to copy (multiple times) the same folder and other files and now it’s super fast as it should be. What could have been the problem the first time? I didn’t have any program in background eating resources when I tried and I have a very powerful PC (AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX).

I’m on Kubuntu 22.04 with latest 6.2.7 kernel and I’ve always tried with the same USB port which is an USB 3.0 type.